# Jmeter как получив один токен запустить от него несколько потоков?

Tags: тестирование, jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование

Я запрашиваю токен, через экстрактор передаю его в Header Manager. Подскажите
как можно запустить запрос HTTP Request (на скрине) в нескольких потоках в цикле, так чтобы токен был вызван только один раз за эти несколько циклов? Потом через минуту повторить (получение токена, запуск HTTP Request).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое - использовать 2 Thread Groups, в одной получаете токен, в другой используете его.

Передавать токен между Thread Groups можно двумя способами:

1. В первой использовать функцию [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) чтобы сконвертировать его в property (они глобальные для всех Thread Groups), во второй значение можно прочитать функцией [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
2. Использовать [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)